# Run a command programmatically with Primefaces

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I want to know if it is possible to run a command programmatically using Primefaces, and in some cases, display a growl. Specifically, I want to alert the user if there is something new in a table in a DB.

I think there are a Primefaces component to execute a command each 5 minutes, for example, but i can't find it.

Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the p:poll of primefaces

(the interval is being set in seconds)

here an example:

[Ajax Poll](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf)